D365 Synapse Link Incremental (CSV) GlobalOptionSetMetadata error
I am testing the new synapse link with incremental data in csv format to adls by using the ADF template Copy Dataverse data into Azure SQL using Synapse Link.
Pipeline is working fine except for the copy activity for GlobalOptionSetMetadata. In the table creation script generated by default in the template I have the following:
"""
    CREATE TABLE '+ @schemaName + '.' + '[' + @tablePrefix + 'GlobalOptionSetMetadata](
    [OptionSetName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Option] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsUserLocalizedLabel] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LocalizedLabelLanguageCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LocalizedLabel] [nvarchar](700) NULL,
    [GlobalOptionSetName] [varchar](128) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''''),
    [EntityName] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [GlobalOptionSetName] ASC,
    [OptionSetName] ASC,
    [Option] ASC,
    [IsUserLocalizedLabel] ASC,
    [LocalizedLabelLanguageCode] ASC,
    [EntityName] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]';

"""
In the csv file I am getting via Synapse Link I see that I have one extra column. Does anyone know how I can get rid of this extra column in the csv file? 

Thanks in advance!

Can you map the columns manually instead of automapping in the sink transformation?
